# docker-compose up <service> does not launch <service> properly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

**Context:** I have a master-worker system on `celery` + `rabbitmq` stack.
System is dockerized( `worker` service is not presented here )

```
version: '2'
services:
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass
        ports:
            - "5672:5672"

    master:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        links:
            - rabbit
        depends_on:
            - rabbit
```

When i execute `docker-compose up` - everything OK!
[image]

**Problems:** But I can't use `docker-compose up`, I need to use `docker-compose master` and `docker-compose worker` (two separate commands for worker and master machines). So, when I execute `docker-compose master` - the container launches, but hangs up!:
[image]

**Research:** I have found out, that it hangs up on task submitting:
`result = longtime_add.delay(count)` Where `longtime_add` is a task.

Full code: https://github.com/waryak/MastersDiploma/tree/vlad

Also, please, edit the title - I feel, that it needs more clear title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried `docker-compose up rabbit master` and it worked out. That's strange, because i can see no external differences in broker logs or any other logs. Also, docker documentation assured, that all depended services would be launched...

Answer (score 2):

A couple of quick points:  (1) I didn't see the expected output messages for the producer broker url that you have in github; (2) I couldn't find where `/src/network` was added to your pythonpath; and (3) the code that loads the producer broker url in `celery.py` looks wrong as it is looking for the `CONFIG` variable and not `PRODUCE_BROKER_URL` as it is in the `variables.env` file.  The reason that the producer would timeout is if it can't connect to the broker, so you'r eon the right track by printing out the produce and worker broker URLs.  It may just be easier for you to try hardcoding the `broker_url` in the producer first:

```
from celery.app import Celery
app = Celery(broker_url='amqp://admin:mypass/rabbit:56772')
app.send_task(name='messages.tasks.longtime_add', kwargs={})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my broker works fine, when i launch it with `docker-compose-up` - it's sending tasks and workers recieve tasks! Problem starts only when i change `docker-compose up` to `docker-compose up master` - i pointed it out in the question